# React Admin! If get an API error then should redirect to login page

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I want that if I get an error like "Invalid Session" from APIs then should redirect to the login page. How can I achieve this in React-Admin by Marmelab?

Answer (score 0):

It happens automatically if you return `Promise.reject()` in `authProvider.checkError` function.